# Solving this $ \lim_{n\to \infty}\Bigg[ \ln \Bigg( \prod_{k=1}^{n}\Big(\frac {k^2+n^2}{n^2}\Big)^k\Bigg)^\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigg] $ in traditional way

Tags: limits, power-series

I am stuck here and can't proceed further. I know that there is another way to solve this. But I want to see the conclusion of this approach. So, what to do next?
$$
\begin{align}
L = \lim_{n\to \infty}\Bigg[ \ln \Bigg( \prod_{k=1}^{n}\Big(\frac {k^2+n^2}{n^2}\Big)^k\Bigg)^\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigg]
 =\lim_{n\to \infty}\Bigg[\ln \Bigg( \prod_{k=1}^{n}\Big(1+\frac {k^2}{n^2}\Big)^\frac{k}{n^2}\Bigg)\Bigg]
 =\lim_{n\to \infty}\Bigg[ \sum_{ k=1}^{n}\Bigg( \ln\Big(1+\frac {k^2}{n^2}\Big)^\frac{k}{n^2}\Bigg)\Bigg]
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned in previous comments, you have
$L=\lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n}\ln(1+(\frac{k}{n})^2)=\int_0^1x\ln(1+x^2)dx$

Comment: As I said in the post I know another way to solve it. You have got that very approach. But my intention is to solve the sum at first then to solve the limit as we traditionally do.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

As a first step, you can do
$$
\begin{split}
L &= \lim_{n\to \infty}
     \Bigg[\sum_{k=1}^n \Bigg(\ln\Big(1+\frac {k^2}{n^2}\Big)^{k/n^2}\Bigg)\Bigg]\\
  &= \lim_{n\to \infty}
     \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n^2}
                        \ln\left(1+\frac {k^2}{n^2}\right)\right) \\
  &= \lim_{n\to \infty}
     \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1n \frac{k}{n} \ln\left(1+\frac {k^2}{n^2}\right)
\end{split}
$$

Comment: I would suggest actually leaving the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ inside the sum, because the form $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{k}{n}\cdot\ln(1+(\frac{k}{n})^2)$ is extremely suggestive.

Comment: @NickPeterson +1 rewrote in your format